# C# - Returning a single value (any datatype) from a DataTable as a string

Tags: c#, string, datatable, field

I've loaded a table from excel in C# using the ExcelDataReader package, however I'm struggling to write a method which returns the value of a cell as a string, based on the row number and column name.

I have a solution for a method that works if there are just strings in the DataTable...

```
public string ReadData(int rowNum, string columnName)
{
    DataRow row = table.Rows[rowNum];
    string value = row.Field<string>(columnName);
    return value;
}
```

(the DataTable variable 'table' is loaded elsewhere)
..however I would like also like to be able to return numbers and dates (as strings).

I feel I might need to edit this part somehow...

```
string value = row.Field<string>(columnName);
```

But I don't know how to make it so it pulls back whatever value and type is in that field and returns a string.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the by-name-indexer and call `ToString()`:

```
string value = row[columnName].ToString();
```

You probably should check for `null` values:

```
string value = (row[columnName] ?? string.Empty).ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Was quite fairly straightforward in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could use, `DataRow` [`name-indexer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an `object` on which we can call `.ToString()` to convert it to `string`.

```
return row[columnname].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
string value = Convert.ToString(row[columnName]);
```

Using `Convert.ToString()` is preferrable because it does not only check for `null` but also for `DBNull`, which is the value of the column when accessing a real database where the column has no content.

Answer (score 0):

In C# 6.0:

```
return row[columnName]?.ToString();
```